# sudoku solver infinite recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog, backtracking

I am writing a sudoku solver. It has been a long time since I have touched prolog, thus I don't remember everything regarding unification, backtracking, etc. I think that I cause the system to backtrack forever (but I don't get any stack exceptions - at least not immediately). This is what I have so far (the puzzle can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sudoku-by-L2G-20050714.svg):

```
% representation of the example puzzle
puzzle([5, 3, _, _, 7, _, _, _, _],
       [6, _, _, 1, 9, 5, _, _, _],
       [_, 9, 8, _, _, _, _, 6, _],
       [8, _, _, _, 6, _, _, _, 3],
       [4, _, _, 8, _, 3, _, _, 1],
       [7, _, _, _, 2, _, _, _, 6],
       [_, 6, _, _, _, _, 2, 8, _],
       [_, _, _, 4, 1, 9, _, _, 5],
       [_, _, _, _, 8, _, _, 7, 9]).

% solve(S)
% the starting point of the program
% saves the solution in the variable S
solve(R1, R2, C1) :-
    % save the rows into variables
    puzzle(R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9),
    % solve for each row
    allunique(R1), allunique(R2), allunique(R3),
    allunique(R4), allunique(R5), allunique(R6),
    allunique(R7), allunique(R8), allunique(R9),
    % the columns must be created first
    nelement(R1, 1, C11), nelement(R2, 1, C21), nelement(R3, 1, C31),
    nelement(R4, 1, C41), nelement(R5, 1, C51), nelement(R6, 1, C61),
    nelement(R7, 1, C71), nelement(R8, 1, C81), nelement(R9, 1, C91),
    C1 = [C11, C21, C31, C41, C51, C61, C71, C81, C91],
    allunique(C1).

% allunique(List)
% Succeeds if all the numbers of List are between 1-9
% and each number exists only once
allunique([]). % Recursion stops when the list is empty

% A member should be between 1-9 and not a member of the tail
allunique([H|T]) :-
    allunique(T),
    member(H, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    not(member(H, T)).

% nelement(List, N-th, X)
% Saves the nth element of a list in variable X
nelement([H|_], 1, H). % The first element is the head

% All other elements will be found in the tail
nelement([_|T], N, X) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N-1,
    nelement(T, N1, X).
```

The line `allunique(C1)` causes the problem. It seems that the system puts a 7 in the first empty box of the 1st column and never changes it (or at least not in the near future). An example C1 list is `[5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6]`.  I am curious to find out why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your example list `[5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6]` doesn't satisfy `allunique` since it contains `8` twice.
2. `solve/3` is incorrect since it checks all rows, but only one column and no "region" (the 3x3 squares).
3. The `solve/1` predicate promised in the comments doesn't appear, so I can't test your code; `allunique/1` and `nelement/3` seem fine.
4. Even if you complete this program, I doubt it's ever going to return an answer. I've seen similar Prolog programs run for hours without finding the solution. Check out [CLP(fd)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) if you want to do this fast (link is for SWI, but SICStus, GNU, and ECLiPSe have similar libraries.)

Comment: You can use the code. The solve/1 is not implemented yet since I've a problem. It is solve/3 for now just for demonstration - Are you familiar with prolog? Just execute solve(X,Y,Z) to see the results. My "example" is what the system is trying to do since the 3rd value of column 1 is not set by me. I'm pretty sure that an efficient solution can be found without using CLP or even optimizations like the cut operator. There are already on the web but I don't like copy-paste programming...

Comment: @faif, your `allunique/3` is provably correct for proper lists (albeit not for its description). I don't get your example as output. The problem is that you're cycling through 2.4e23 possibilities in `solve/3` to find the one for which the column also matches. (Cut won't help either. You need a different algorithm than naïve backtracking if you ever want to solve sudokus.)

Comment: You were right about the performance. The problem was the allunique predicate. When I use clpfd and replace it with all_different a solution is found immediately. Thanks for the tip. I hoped that a solution would be possible without any additional libraries, but it seems that it is not (at least when using a simple approach)... To get the result of the example you need to comment the last allunique call since it won't terminate :)

Comment: I did that. Note that there is also 1 more problem with the code that I just noticed. nelement/3 should call itself, instead of the element/3 predicate. But I just updated that in the provided code, since it is not the core of the problem.